# LTC3625 Not working as expected with LTSpice

Tags: charger, supercapacitor

I am using LTspice with LTC3625.  Circuit A (1st Image) works well as expected. Circuit B introduces R2 a 25 Ohm current limiting resistor. Circuit B (2nd image failes to reach the required output voltage)  Only change is R2.

Can anyone please explain why ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

R1 (the PROG input) has a value that attempts to force the chip to feed the output capacitors with 2 amps. Having R2 at 25 ohms is going to run the chip into a reset problem once current starts charging the output capacitors so, if you are trying to limit the output capacitor current, adding R2 is the wrong way to do it - change R1 to a much higher value such as 500 kohm to get a charge current of about 300 mA.

Comment: Is there any reason for this to be downvoted?

Comment: Dear Andy,  THANK YOU !!!   Your explanation was excellent and i did find the graph in the datasheet that explained the values of R.  I used a bigger value and it did indeed result in lower input current.   PS: No idea why anyone would down vote your answer.

Comment: Dear Andy,  any suggestions how to reduce the input current in this MPPT circuit please ?

Comment: What MPPT circuit?

Comment: I opened a new question as its technically a different question.  Please see the new question.  Thank you Andy